# Load in jQuery into a SVG open as a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom, svg

I am able to hook mouse events on SVG elements by going into it with the Chrome Web Inspector, assigning an `id` to the SVG polygon tag, and then using the native `$()` which is equivalent to `document.getElementById` to hook it:

```
$("#THISONE").addEventListener('click', function() { console.log('clicked it'); });
```

Now I want to make this slightly less painful to work with so it'd be nice if I can get jQuery DOM methods to work with.

So...

```
(function() {                                          
    var jq = document.createElement('script');         
    jq.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js";
    document.appendChild(jq);                                                
})();
```

produces `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null`. So apparently even `document` doesn't exist. `document` is accessible from the js console, but this function loaded as a bookmarklet does not work.

I then tried pasting the contents into the js console, it produces this:

```
Error: HierarchyRequestError: DOM Exception 3
code: 3
message: "HierarchyRequestError: DOM Exception 3"
name: "HierarchyRequestError"
stack: "Error: A Node was inserted somewhere it doesn't belong.↵    at <anonymous>:4:10↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:602:39)↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:521:52)↵    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:440:21)"
__proto__: DOMException
```

Any tips?

My ideal goal is to have a bookmarklet that I can use on any SVG i open in Chrome that will install a delegated event handler that can do things like respond to clicks on certain elements to provide popups or change colors.

In particular I'm dealing with enormous SVGs of graphs produced by `dot`. These graphs have long snakey edge paths which overlap in such a way that it is near-impossible to follow them. So, I want to highlight just the edges incident on a node if I click the node.

Failing that, I will resort to some hack that embeds the svg into a html webpage, or is linked from a resource. Somewhat less elegant but workable enough.

Comment: There's no head (not even a document apparently) in the document. `document.getElementsByTagName('head')` produces `[]`

Comment: Is this SVG inline in a html document or is the SVG in its own document i.e. what's the root node is it `<html>` or `<svg>`